# iCloud login fails with correct password

Tags: icloud, password

The iCloud system preferences on a MacBook continues to display "enter your password to continue using iCloud" even when the password is entered correctly and verified working with an iPhone and icloud.com.

```
com.apple.iCloudHelper  AOSKit ERROR: Delegate login request failed, appleID=user@email.null, hasPassword=1, httpStatusCode=401
com.apple.iCloudHelper  AOSKit INFO: (user@email.null) GS: Verify successful (foundToken=1)
com.apple.iCloudHelper  AOSKit INFO: (user@email.null) GS: Renew successful (foundToken=1, iCloud=1, appleID=1)
com.apple.iCloudHelper  AOSKit INFO: XPC SERVER: Called PCS setup with appleID=user@email.null, p=1, dsid=2293764942, id=(null) (err=Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-25293 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -25293 - Failed to add: ProtectedCloudStorage)" (errKCAuthFailed / errSecAuthFailed:  / Authorization/Authentication failed.) UserInfo=0x7feddc2d7511 {NSDescription=Failed to add: ProtectedCloudStorage})
com.apple.iCloudHelper  AOSKit ERROR: XPC SERVER: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-25293 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -25293 - Failed to add: ProtectedCloudStorage)" (errKCAuthFailed / errSecAuthFailed:  / Authorization/Authentication failed.) UserInfo=0x7faddb2d7500 {NSDescription=Failed to add: ProtectedCloudStorage} (appleID=user@email.null, dsid=2293764942)
com.apple.iCloudHelper  AOSKit INFO: XPC SERVER: Called _CSAddAppleIDAccount() with appleID=user@email.null, p=1, didAdd=0 (err=Error Domain=CSIdentityErrorDomain Code=-100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (CSIdentityErrorDomain error -100.)")
com.apple.iCloudHelper  AOSKit ERROR: XPC SERVER: Error Domain=CSIdentityErrorDomain Code=-100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (CSIdentityErrorDomain error -100.)"
com.apple.iCloudHelper  AOSKit WARN: (com.apple.systempreferences/14.0) AOSKC (2293764942): No kc item found (perhaps because no account has been configured), error -25293, hasAccountData=0, validAccountDataLen=0, attemptNum=1 (dsidStr=2293764942) <client=com.apple.accountsd/113, clientSessionID=100009[hasGraphicAccess=1,kcAccess=111,uid=501], serviceSessionID=100009[hasGraphicAccess=1,kcAccess=111,uid=501], clientPort=10755, didAutoJoinFail=0, pid=20573, currSessionID=100009[hasGraphicAccess=1,kcAccess=111,uid=501]>
com.apple.iCloudHelper  AOSKit WARN: (com.apple.systempreferences/14.0) AOSKC (user@email.null): Failed to generate key data (dsid=2293764942, p=0x0, pc=0, ac=0)
com.apple.iCloudHelper  AOSKit WARN: (com.apple.systempreferences/14.0) AOSKC (user@email.null): No key available for storage
com.apple.iCloudHelper  AOSKit ERROR: (com.apple.systempreferences/14.0) Failed to store account info for appleID=user@email.null, env=PROD
```

It looks like the issue is macOS being unable to store the password or access it on the MacBook. I tried deleting all iCloud entries in the Keychain but it didn't help.

Comment: you didn't have the caps lock key set, did you?  I've done that.

Comment: I tried entering an incorrect password to test the login, it does return an error when the password is wrong.